# complicated json to pojo

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

Can you please help me with designing pojo class for json like this, where property used as value?

```
{"1":
    {
    "12.08.2014":
        {"start_time":"09:00","end_time":"11:00"},
    "15.08.2014":
        {"start_time":"09:00","end_time":"11:00"},
    }
,
"2":
    {
    "25.08.2014":
        {"start_time":"09:00","end_time":"11:00"},
    "27.08.2014":
        {"start_time":"09:00","end_time":"11:00"},
    "29.08.2014":
        {"start_time":"09:00","end_time":"11:00"}
    }
}
```

i want to get some like this

```
class POJO {
    class Schedule{
        @JsonProperty("start_time")
        String startTime;
        @JsonProperty("end_time")
        String endTime;

        @JSON???????
        String date;
    }
    @?????????
    List<Schedule> scheduleList;
}
```

Comment: i google for tutorials, but every examples just simple property : value cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it as a Map of maps. and the inner time details as a custom object. So end result would be like `Map<String, Map<String, Time>>`. Then you a json parser like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to parse the value. Eg

Jackson style

```
public class Time {
    @JsonProperty(value="start_time")
    private String startTime;
    @JsonProperty(value="end_time")
    private String endTime;

    // Getter Setter
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Map<String, Time>> data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, Time>>>() {});
```

Gson style

```
class Time {
    @SerializedName(value="start_time")
    private String startTime;
    @SerializedName(value="end_time")
    private String endTime;

    // Getters Setters
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Map<String, Time>> data = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Time>>>() {}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
class MyItem{
    String id;
    List<MyEvent> events;
}

class MyEvent{
    Date eventDate;
    int startTime;
    int endTime;
}
```

Of course, you need to write a parser.

Comment: so, it's impossible to use ObjectMapper to auto parse it?

Comment: afaik, it's impossible.